# Alarm (notification) sound suddenly stops working in iOs

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, uilocalnotification

In my app you have the option to watch a certain given area. When the boundaries are crossed a notification is given. An alertView and Sound when the app is in the foreground and a notification with the alarm sound when the app is in the background. When the app is in the foreground everything is ok. When in the background, not notification is given and no alarm sound is played. It has worked fine before.

Here is my code:

```
// Show alertview when active and show localNotification when inactive

-(void)AlertViewShow{

    if (i == 1) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString (@"Alert",@"")
                          message:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertMoving",@"")
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertOK",@"")
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource: @"ALARM"
                                             withExtension:@"WAV"];
    avSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
    avSound.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [avSound play];
}
i = 2;
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    if ([avSound isPlaying]) {
        [avSound stop];
    }
}
if (i == 2) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

}

}

- (void)localNotification {

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = nil;
localNotif.alertBody = NSLocalizedString (@"NotifAlert",@"");
localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString (@"NotifView",@"");
localNotif.soundName = @"ALARMSHORT.wav";
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

}

// END Show alertview when active and show localNotification when inactive
```

Does anyone know what is changed so why it is suddenly not working anymore?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "before"? Did it stop working on a new device? Maybe it's the iOS version?

Comment: @phi, thank you for responding. What I ment by 'before' is that it has worked on my devices and on devices of customers as well. Now I got a report it's not working and on my device iPhone 6s plus with iOs 10.3.3 it is not. I did not notice this before, therefor it is possible that the problem excists a bit longer. It appears that I did not tested it enough when a new iOs version was released. Shame on me. I'm not a very skilled developer. This project was a one timer but now I'm in trouble because there are thousands installs. So your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If I were you, my first priority would be to try and reproduce the bug. Make sure you understand under which circumstances it happens. To me, the code you posted does not seem very relevant to the problem.

Comment: I am able to reproduce it on my own device. It is really happening on my iPhone6 plus with iOs 10.3.3. I'm trying to run it on the simulator but there I get a SIGABRT error. That's maybe caused by some depricated code. I'm trying to solve it as well but i don't understand it quite yet. I make a new post of that issue for some help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `scheduleLocalNotification:` which is [deprecated in iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623005-schedulelocalnotification). Try to update to `UNUserNotificationCenter` and see if your problem persists.

Comment: thank you but can you tell me how to do it? Sorry, I'm feeling so stupid but it seems I'm totally lost and don't understand how to do it...... :-(. What a shame on me......

Answer (score 0):

```
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
        UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        content.title = @"Title";
        content.body = @"Alert Body";
        content.badge = @([content.badge integerValue] + 1);
        content.userInfo = userInfo;//userInfo is a dictionary
        if ([sound isEqualToString:@"default"]) {
            content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
        }else {
            content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"customsound"];
        }

        UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:NO];

        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CaptainLocalNotification-%@,",userInfo[@"pushId"]];
        UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                              content:content trigger:trigger];

        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        UILocalNotification *local = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
        local.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        local.alertBody = alertBody;
        local.applicationIconBadgeNumber = local.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1;
        if ([sound isEqualToString:@"default"]) {
            local.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        }else {
            local.soundName = @"customsound";
        }
        local.userInfo = userInfo;//userInfo is a dictionary
        local.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
    }
```